# How to make sure every polygon is labeled in data driven pages?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, data-driven-pages

as part of my job I have to label sections of pavement on road networks that can span for many miles and often take up several data driven pages that I have laid out at the scale required by our clients.

The problem is that since some of these segments span multiple pages, they are only labeled once. So what often happens is that it will be labeled in one DDP and not the other ones. I've asked people who have previously held my position and they say the best way they've found it so just manually create new annotations as you go through the DDP's.

Is there a setting of some sort that I can make every polygon and polyline in a DDP individually labeled or anything that would make this process a little less tedious?
[image: Example]

Comment: Look at the Label Density tab in the Placement Properties for labels.  There are several options there that might interest you most notably the Repeat Label one.

Answer (score 1):

First step would be converting the labels in your shapefile into an annotation file. Then, do the following:

1. Open your annotation file attribute table and add a column called "Page Number"
2. For each label, enter the appropriate page number. Use the field calculator if you have many labels for each page. Also, If a label exist on two pages, you'll have to make a copy of the label and have that label with two different page numbers. It will make sense soon.
3. After you're done assigning page numbers for each label,
   in your annotation file go to "Layer Properties > Definition Query >
   Page Definition", Click "Enable". Pick the "Page Name Field" (in
   this case: "Page Number") and check "Match".
4. Go back to your map in "Layout View" and now you will see only the labels that belong to each page.
5. You can make copies of labels using the "Edit" tool and move labels using the "Select" tool.